Playwright C# SpecFlow - Each Browser for Each Scenario
Can someone help to design a setup with the below requriements

Create a Driver.cs File ( should take care of playwright , browser and page)
Create a Hooks Class ( should take care of before, after scenarios......)
How do we make sure that each scenario gets the seperate browser
how do we pass the details to page classes and step definitions

tried the above and somehow messed up with the static and getting the error as PAge already closed

Please see Why is "Can someone help me?" not a useful question?. This is too broad--please share your attempt and full error message as a [mcve]. Thanks.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
